# error: src refspec development does not match any al hacer un push

Tags: git, gitlab

Cuando intento hacer un push a la rama development de mi repositorio obtengo el error

> error: src refspec development does not match any.

Esto es lo que he hecho:

1 - cloné el repositorio

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:solay-Apache/koica-inscriptions.git
```

2 - creeéuna nueva rama y me posicioné en esa rama:

```
git branch db
git checkout db
```

3 - hice un pull de la rama development del repositorio remoto

```
git pull origin development
```

4 - hice cambios en el código del proyecto y realicé un commit

```
git add .
git commit -m "mensaje"
```

5 - hago un push a la rama development del repositorio remoto

```
git push origin development
```

6 - al hacer el push obtengo el error

> ```
> error: src refspec development does not match any.
> error: fallo el push de algunas referencias
> ```

Información adicional:

```
$ git show-ref
refs/heads/db
refs/heads/master
refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
refs/remotes/origin/development
refs/remotes/origin/master

$ git remote -v
origin  git@gitlab.com:solay-Apache/koica-inscriptions.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:solay-Apache/koica-inscriptions.git (push)
```

Comment: Puedes intentar agregando el argumento -u? git push -u origin develpment

Comment: ya lo hice así y sigue dando el mismo problema.

Comment: Creo que tu problema esta basado en que no existe tu rama **db**, para que exista tiene que tener por lo menos un commit, entonces por eso te dice que no hace **match** con ninguna

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estuve haciendo los mismo pasos que muestras y en efecto sale el mismo error.

Lo que puedo entender es que como no estás haciendo push a la misma rama db, y lo estás haciendo a otra rama, esta rama no existe en tu local, no encuentra development.

por lo tanto, deberías usar el nombre en el remoto: `refs/remotes/origin/development`

Así lo solucioné:

```
git push origin refs/remotes/origin/development
```

Ahora, esa es una solución a tu pregunta.

Lo otro que podrías hacer es:

- Subir la rama `db` y hacer un Merge Request a la rama `development`.
- Crear la rama `development` en tu local y subirla desde esa rama.

  ```
  git branch refs/remotes/origin/development        
  git checkout -b development
  #Hacer los cambios
  git add .
  git commit -m "mensaje"
  git push origin development
  ```

Comment: Revisar [answer] , agrega de que forma  realizar  lo que comentas.

Comment: Si añadieras el comando a ejecutar en cada uno de los pasos, esta respuesta mejoraría considerablemente y sería más fácil de aplicar para los usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un probleam similar, en mi caso la rama local se llamaba "master". Al realizar lo siguiente funcionó sin ningun inconveniente.

```
git push origin master
```

Estaba utilizando este comando que generaba conflicto:

```
git push origin main
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenia el mismo problema y lo que hice fue ejecutar el siguiente comando.

```
git branch -M main
```

Y luego subir el repositorio.

```
git push -u origin main
```